# How do you mock ViewData so it can be used in code for unit tests?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

If you have code that adds data to the ViewData then retrieves it in another part of the code, how do you inject the ViewData so you can add and retrieve data from it in unit tests?

For example, my code that I want to test adds data to the ViewData

```
ViewData.Add("MyData", myDataObject);
```

And other code that checks it and acts on it based on its value:

```
var myDataObject = ViewData["MyData"] as MyDataObject;
if(myDataObject.MyProp == "somevalue"){ myService.GetSomething() }
```

Then I want to verify in a unit test that the service is called because of the ViewData value.

```
myService.Verify(m => m.GetSomething("somevalue"), Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a useable ViewData object in your object under test in your unit tests like this (using Moq and Xunit):

```
    // Arrange
    #region Mock ViewData

    var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
    var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
    var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new PageActionDescriptor(), modelState);
    var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
    var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, modelState);
    var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
    var pageContext = new PageContext(actionContext)
    {
        ViewData = viewData
    };

    #endregion

    var myService = new Mock<ISomeService>();
    myService.Setup(p => p.
        GetSomething(lwp, "somevalue"))
    .Returns(someData);

    var myObjectImTesting = new PageModel(
        myService.Object)
    {
        // inject the mock ViewData into the object under test
        PageContext = pageContext,
        TempData = tempData
    };

    // Act
    await myObjectImTesting.OnGetAsync();

    // Assert
    myService.Verify(m => m.GetSomething("somevalue"), Times.Once);
```